# Dynamic items in viewholder on RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

If we have N categories (between 1 and 100 according to a REST API) and each with X items (between 1 and 50, depending on the category), what is the best way to do a category RecyclerView?

[image: Schematic image.]

To add do this I am adding card views for each item item of a category in the method "onBindViewHolder" like this:

```
    @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MoviesViewHolder holder, int i) {
    holder.title.setText(items.get(i).getTitle());

     // I add a CardView (item_category.xml) for each item in the list

    for (ObjectShort object: items.get(i).getObjects()) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_category, holder.linearCategories, false);
        ImageView img = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.iv_wallpaper);
        imageLoader.load(img, object.getImg().getPoster().getThumbnail());
        holder.linearCategories.addView(view);
    }

}
```

And when it is recycled I remove the ITEMS elements in "onViewRecycled" because if I do not do it when doing vertical scrolling and reloading a category, items are added again duplicating:

```
    @Override
public void onViewRecycled(MoviesViewHolder holder) {
    // delete all items 
    holder.linearCategories.removeAllViews();
}
```

Is there any better way to do it? This is not effective and the scroll is very slow

thanks to all

Comment: probably you can add another RecyclerView instead of linearCategories there, this way images will be inflated only when on screen (on in the exactly side)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your question, I'm going to go back to the old days of `ListView`. Let's imagine that I had a simple list where each row was just a title and an image. A really naive implementation of `getView()` to support that list might look like this:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.itemview, parent, false);

    TextView title = view.findViewById(R.id.title);
    title.setText("hello world");

    ImageView image = view.findViewById(R.id.image);
    image.setImageResource(R.drawable.my_image);

    return view;
}
```

There's two major sources of performance trouble in this implementation:

1. We're inflating a new view every time
2. We're calling `findViewById()` every time

Number 1 was solved by making use of the `convertView` parameter, and number 2 was solved by something called the "view holder pattern". When the Google dev team created the `RecyclerView` API to replace `ListView`, they made "view holders" a first-class citizen, and now everyone works with `RecyclerView.ViewHolder`s by default.

It's important to remember that the performance gains of avoiding repeated view inflation and repeated view lookup were **so valuable** that Google baked them into the new system.

Now let's look at your code...

> ```
> public void onBindViewHolder(MoviesViewHolder holder, int i) {
>     ...
>     for (ObjectShort object: items.get(i).getObjects()) {
>         LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
>         View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_category, holder.linearCategories, false);
>         ImageView img = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.iv_wallpaper);
>         imageLoader.load(img, object.getImg().getPoster().getThumbnail());
>         holder.linearCategories.addView(view);
>     }
> }
> ```

This `for` loop inside your bind method has all the same problems that my naive `getView()` implementation above had. Inflating a new view for each item in the category, and invoking `findViewById()` to get ahold of its `ImageView` is going to be expensive, especially when the user flings the list.

To fix your performance problems, just apply the same logic to your "inner" list of content as you have to your "outer" content: use a `RecyclerView` for items (inside each `ViewHolder` for categories).

Here is a really simple sample app that illustrates my solution: https://gist.github.com/zizibaloob/2eb64f63ba8d1468100a69997d525a54